# How to populate Select box dynamically from API response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, antd

I'm trying to create select box dynamically from api response in react. below is the api response

```
{
    "land": [{
        "land_id": 15,
        "name": "zipku",
        "description": "zipku"
    }, {
        "land_id": 16,
        "name": "jumba",
        "description": "jumba"
    }],
    "type": [{
        "type_id": 1,
        "name": "s_id",
        "description": "s_id"
    }, {
        "type_id": 2,
        "name": "s_id2",
        "description": "s_id2"
    }],
    "nationality": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Japan",
        "description": "Japan"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Hong_Kong",
        "description": "Hong_Kong"
    }]
}
```

I am using react with ant design.
what I have did so far

```
                        Object.keys(myObject).map((idx, i) => {
                            return (<Select key={i}
                                {...myObject[idx].map((selec, i) => (
                                    <Option value={selec.name}>{selec.name}}</Option>
                                ))}

                            >

                            </Select>)
                        })
```

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: {selec.name} **}**?

Comment: How are you actually calling the API and handling the response? That'll likely be where the issue is.

Comment: it is showing undefined. I am trying to access name key here of each inner object.

Comment: @Nick I am getting values from redux state. The response is valid and I want to loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
  Object.keys(myObject).map((idx, i) => {
                        return (<Select key={i}>
                           {myObject[idx].map((selec, i) => (
                                <Option value={selec.name}>{selec.name}</Option>
                            ))}
                        </Select>)
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was trying for.